# passing an argument into mayabatch python command

Tags: python, batch-file, maya

```
set /p VAR=User input

for /r . %%a in (*.ma) do ( 
        mayabatch -file %%a -command "python(""import script"" + ""\n"" + ""script.main(%VAR%)"")" 
)
```

I'm writing a bat file to run maya batch to process a bunch of files.  I need to run python code passing in an argument %VAR%  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: edited original post.  %VAR% is just user input, directly before this for loop.  In my case %VAR% is a string I'd like to validate in all the files I'm iterating through.

Comment: I'd recommend to use the powershell to do this type of tasks, scripting is very much easier.